# Rename current file in vim

Tags: files, vim, rename

Searching over net shows `:f filename` would rename the current file in `vim`. But executing this and later exiting `vim`, shows the new file with all the contents and also the old file is present with the saved content untill executing the above command.

So, how can we rename the current file we are editing in `vim` ?

**EDIT** - Any solution that does not involve a plugin, as I guess that would require administrative privileges which I don't have. Any tweaks with config or mapping ?

Comment: You do not need root privileges to install normal vim plugins. As normal user, you can install them to the `.vim` subdirectory in your home folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this](http://www.readncode.com/blog/how-to-rename-a-file-in-vim/) plugin as useful for you. Once you install it you get the opportunity to use :rename, which does what the mv command does on Unix. Also you might get some ideas from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205286/renaming-the-current-file-in-vim) for other alternatives.

Comment: It would be nice if you can add a short explanation on each link.